# How to calculate the memory space occupied by the following struct?

Tags: c++, memory, struct

I need to make the memory model of a struct for that I need to find that how much memory is allocated to a struct when declared.

```
struct student {       
        int Roll_no,age;
        float average;
        float grade;     
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot problem has been solved. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand you, the builtin `sizeof` operator/function does what you want:

```
size_t size_of_student_in_bytes = sizeof(student);
```